# How to get unique value from dynamically create divs by using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, dom-manipulation

I am creating div inside div tag on button click, It is created and shown on UI , but
I am unable to get the unique value  inserted in dynamic created div. I always get
the first  value.
Code sample:

```
<div id="row-list-outer"> </div>
```

Dynamically adding code sample, This code runs on each click

```
 $("#row-list-outer").append(` <div class="row g-3">
                     <div>                                  
                       <input type="text" id="salesPersonName" placeholder="Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>)
```

Now input element  is created on click, but If I enter a value  in 2nd row input, or 3rd row input etc. Then How  I get those values in the same order as they are inserted. For example if the user enters in first row input, then it should be stored on index 0 in array, similarly, if user enters in 1 row, 2nd row, then it should be inserted on array at index 1, 2 respectively

Comment: when do you want to insert the value into an array. While typing into the text field or after filling all the inputs then clicking another button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function addRow() {
  $("#row-list-outer").append(`<div class="row g-3">
                     <div>                                  
                       <input type="text" id="salesPersonName${$("input[id^=salesPersonName]").length + 1}" placeholder="Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>`)
}

$(document).on("change","input[id^=salesPersonName]",function() {
  var v = $("input[id^=salesPersonName]").map(function() {
    return $(this).val() || ""
  }).get();
  console.log(v)
})
```

**Demo**

```js
function addRow() {
  $("#row-list-outer").append(`<div class="row g-3">
                     <div>                                  
                       <input type="text" id="salesPersonName${$("input[id^=salesPersonName]").length + 1}" placeholder="Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>`)
}

$(document).on("change","input[id^=salesPersonName]",function() {
  var v = $("input[id^=salesPersonName]").map(function() {
    return $(this).val() || ""
  }).get();
  console.log(v)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row-list-outer"> </div>


<button onclick="addRow()">addRow</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:
HTML:

```
  <div id="row-list-outer"> </div>
  <button>Change color</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $("#row-list-outer").append(` <div class="row g-3">
                     <div>                                  
                       <input type="text" class="salesPersonName" 
data-id="${$('.salesPersonName').length + 1}" placeholder="Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>`);
})
let colors = [];
$(document).on("change","input",function(e){
    let i = +$(this).data('id') - 1
  colors[i] = $(this).val();
  console.log(colors)
});
```